# Optimising django queries to avoid duplicates when using detail view and overriding get_context_data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, performance, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to reduce the number of duplicated queries when using CBVs such as `DetailView` and then overriding `get_context_data` to filter a model based on related models.

Right now, I have a `DetailView` for a `PatientCase` model and want to create two variables in the context for a related model `CasePhotos` the relationship is via a foreign key on the `CasePhoto` model.

```
class CasePhoto(models.Model):
    ...
    patient_case = models.ForeignKey(PatientCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.URLField()
    is_mentor_edit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

Now, I know this is bad, but I cannot seem to find the correct optimal way to do this. Some guidance and even better some documentation links that I've obviously overlooked somewhere would be even better.

```
class ReviewCaseView(DetailView):
    model = PatientCase

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    patient_case = self.get_object()
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    case_photos = CasePhoto.objects.filter(patient_case=patient_case)
    context['case_photos'] = case_photos.filter(is_mentor_edit=False)
    context['mentor_photos'] = case_photos.filter(is_mentor_edit=True)
    return context
```

I know that the duplication is line 5 `patient_case = self.get_object()` as `detail.py` calls `get_object` which is what creates the first query. Is there a way of caching this to reuse in `get_context_data` or maybe a better way without `get_context_data` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `DetailView`, the [`get()` method](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get) sets `self.object = get_object()` before calling `get_context_data`, therefore you don't have to call `get_object()` again.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    patient_case = self.object
    case_photos = CasePhoto.objects.filter(patient_case=patient_case)
    context['case_photos'] = case_photos.filter(is_mentor_edit=False)
    context['mentor_photos'] = case_photos.filter(is_mentor_edit=True)
    return context
```

Comment: Top notch answer as usual @Alasdair thanks! I'm getting "similar" queries on the filters for the `case_photos` and `mentor_photos` is there any way of caching these to further reduce hits on the db?

Comment: In theory you could create the `case_photos` and `mentor_photos` by looping through `case_photos`, for example `context['case_photos'] = [p for p in case_photos if not p.is_mentor_edit]`. You would have to benchmark to see if it gave any improvement in practice. Running two similar queries in a view is usually ok, it's the n+1 problem that you really need to look out for (e.g. running one query for every individual photo).